# Há algum problema com minhas respostas?

Tags: suporte, comportamento

Tenho notado que minhas últimas respostas dadas tem recebido poucos votos, e apesar de sempre procurar pesquisar a respeito, testar e demonstrar com algum exemplo e deixar uma explicação, breve ou longa dependendo da complexidade, elas recebem pouca atenção.

O fato é que, por mais que haja conhecimento adquirido e compartilhado em cada um delas(e isso é bastante gratificante para mim, claro), não podemos negar que ver que outras pessoas acharam nosso conteúdo bom também é bastante satisfatório, ainda mais no formato adotado pelos sites da rede SE.

Para termos números em que se basear, fiz essa query que mostra [todas as minhas respostas desde o dia primeiro de abril](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A28595+is%3Aanswer+created%3A2017-04-01T00%3A00%3A00..2017-05-26T19%3A00%3A00+&tab=newest). Do total, a grande maioria está praticamente zerada.

Gostaria de saber o que pode estar acarretando essa pouca visibilidade, se é minha forma de escrever que pode não estar sendo bem clara, ou se o conteúdo das respostas está sendo bastante específico, ou outro motivo que acreditem ser, e se tiverem sugestões, gostaria de saber no que posso melhorar, pois em muitas eu dedico bastante esforço de pesquisa e revisão, além de procurar sempre linkar referências, mas talvez posso estar pecando em algum aspecto que não está óbvio para mim.

Comment: Não olhei detalhadamente a lista, mas em vários casos o horário da postagem (à noite) não ajuda, tem menos gente no site. Se quer "cultivar" votos nas respostas postadas de noite, experimente editá-las durante um horário de mais movimento.

Comment: @bfavaretto pior que já faço isso, o resultado é o mesmo. :/

Comment: @diegofm, essa distribuição de votos é algo social, depende de muitos fatores aleatórios. Por exemplo, eu tenho uma maior tendência à votar num olho que tudo vê e tudo responde do que num Squirtle (mas se fosse um Bulbassauro... a conversa seria outra)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado what? Então você vota de acordo com a foto do autor e não pelo conteudo do que ele gera no site?

Comment: O avatar as vezes me influencia se eu deixo um voto positivo ou não. Ultimamente eu tenho melhorado quanto a isso, mas esse é um fator social que pode interferir na votação

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado discordo, tem varios usuários que tem memes, fotos de personagens de animes e tambem algumas fotos com certas "bizarrices" e nunca vi isso influenciar o voto no conteudo deles. Temos que lembrar que aqui é um site de programação, o que deve ser avaliado é o conteudo, se um usuario inclui a foto do autor como peso do seu voto, ele está no site errado, stackoverflow tem objetivo bem distante de facebook ou instagram. Entenda que isso não é uma critica a você, as vezes acontece da gente e incluir alguns criterios meio estranhos pra votar.

Comment: Tô procurando um artigo que relaciona confiança do público com aparência do cientista ; era mais ou menos assim : quanto mais feio, maior a tendência a achar o cientista inteligente. Se isso se aplica ao mundo científico, talvez isso possa ter impacto aqui. Mas o meu ponto não era específico sobre avatar, isso foi só um exemplo : em contatos sociais, muitos fatores aleatórios estão em campo

Comment: @diegofm sim, concordo que não deveria, mas texto tem um aspecto estético muito importante, inclusive informações extra textuais influenciam nisso. Uma coisa é o que a teoria do comportamento prega, outra é o comportamento humano. Tipo, respostas que resolvem o problema merecem votos positivos, mas é comum que elas não recebam. Não é o devido, é o que se observa

Comment: Editorial sobre [aparência do cientista influir na percepção de outros sobre sua capacidade](http://www.iflscience.com/editors-blog/attractive-scientists-are-deemed-more-interesting-but-less-competent-by-the-public/). Eu não li os estudos citados, mas enfim, fatores que **não deveriam** mas  influenciam

Comment: @diegofm Certa vez aqui no meta, questionei sobre downvoters dentro de um tópico que criei. A resposta de alguns membros foi basicamente : "Isso pode eventualmente acontecer. Mas eles podem fazer isso [sendo errado ou certo]." Isso vale para upvoters.
Então, verdadeiramente não importa o propósito original para que foi criado o StackOverflow, e sim, nessa questão, como a comunidade se comporta. Então critérios 'ruins' com certeza vão influenciar no voto. Dois critérios que considero prejudiciais são: A confiança, e a estima por aquele determinado usuário.

Answer (score 6):

> Isto é um tanto quanto opinião minha, no começo seria um comentário, mas resolvi transformar em resposta

Eu diria que quem pergunta no site sobre Java e principalmente sobre Swing ou Fx não tem o conhecimento básico para entender do assunto, se notar perguntas voltadas para web sempre tem maior visibilidade, o problema eu diria são as pessoas que frequentam a [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) que tem pouco conhecimento para entender as propostas, mesmo em outras linguagens isto ocorre, mas quando se trata de web o publico é um pouco maior ou mais interessado.

Basta notar que as pessoas adoram dar votos em coisas bem simplórias, mesmo que algo repetitivo, isto porque é fácil de entender, se procurar alguma pergunta de java que fale de um simples algorítimo matemático notará que as respostas (se boas) ganham mais atenção:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjava%5d%20is%3aquestion

Veja a primeira logo de cara é sobre como proteger um projeto e a uma que é sobre o operador `+=`, este tipo de pergunta desperta mais o interesse.

Agora quando se trata de APIs e coisas assim nem todo mundo usa ou tem um conhecimento razoável para entender as propostas, as pessoas muitas vezes não votam porque algo é bom de verdade, mas sim porque algo **parece útil**, talvez se [swing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) fosse algo muito usado mesmo muitas pessoas teriam dificuldades e muitas pessoas encontrariam suas respostas e votariam, eu mesmo uso eventualmente Java (para algum algorítimo ou Android), mas swing ou JavaFX é algo bem raro pra mim.

Comment: Mas algumas entre as da busca que são simplórias de java, não sendo de swing. Depois linko algumas especificas aqui, via celular é complicado

Comment: @diegofm Eu só citei o swing como exemplo, mas isto indica quase tudo, veja como por exemplo, "operador `+=`", eu pessoalmente acho uma pergunta tão trivial, mas as pessoas "amam" isso :p. Agora admito que esta resposta aqui é **ótima** (assim como outras respostas suas) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/199542/3635, mas existe uma questão de série de fatores como a hora que postou vs popularidade da linguagem no site vs maneira de se escrever. É muito relativo, eu mesmo tenho os mesmos problemas que você com algumas tags, todos os dias eu vejo respostas horriveis ganharem +3,

Comment: o problema pra mim é o "grau de conhecimento" vs "a suposta utilidade que as pessoas enxergam"

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não é uma questão de "adorar votar em coisas simplórias", ou o "pouco conhecimento de quem frequenta a tag `java`". Perguntas sobre fundamentos recebem mais votos porque, por serem fundamentos, sempre vão ajudar mais pessoas. Não é pra existir correlação absoluta entre **volume** de votos e **complexidade** da resposta. Isso não faz sentido.

Comment: Eu definitivamente não disse neste sentido @Gabe, se eu fiz entender isto então é porque eu não soube me expressar, ainda sim eu acredito que são fatores e que tudo ali é relativo, o que eu queria dizer é mais o comportamento das pessoas que as respostas em si ;)

Comment: Concordo com ambos :) Coisas fundamentais, simples recebem mais votos porque são mais universais, mais fáceis de analisar e exige pouco conhecimento pra ver que está certo. Além de tudo o que foi dito acrescento que estilo de como se dá a resposta também influencia.  Não descarte colecionar inimigos como um fato para as pessoas votarem. Fui até ver o padrão de votação geral e as pessoas votam pouco no diegofm mesmo. Precisaria comparar com outras pessoas, tenho mais o meu parâmetro, mas eu sou meio que um ponto fora da curva. Fica estranho quem dá poucos votos em mim e muito nos outros :)

Comment: Não quero cometer inconfidência com dado privilegiado, mas mesmo na minha avaliação pessoal sem olhar dados sempre percebi que eu votava bastante no diegofm mesmo não podendo votar na maioria do que posta, só não sabia a proporção em relação aos outros.

Comment: Outras coisa talvez seja estilo da resposta. Não posso falar nada, mas pode ser que muitas pessoas não gostem. Sei lá. Eu poderia especular também que algumas pessoas não percebem que você tenha expertise e evitem votar em você. Sim, este seria um voto meio pessoal, tendencioso no bom sentido. Isso acaba contando por mais que a gente não queria. Mas os principais motivos são o que o Gabe e Guilherme falaram.

Comment: @bigown nós já conversamos sobre isso, e pensei em incluir a tal "empatia"(ou apatia rs) como fator, mas como isso não é algo com que eu possa provar ou que seja mensurável com as ferramentas que eu tenho acesso do site, preferi deixar de fora. Mas não deixa de ser verdade este trecho que você citou: `"Não descarte colecionar inimigos como um fato para as pessoas votarem."`.

Comment: @diegofm, sobre perguntas sobre [fundamentos ganhar mais votos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6028/h%c3%a1-algum-problema-com-minhas-respostas#comment23072_6030), a minha resposta mais bem quista na comunidade foi essa [sobre Git](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210655/64969). Não é uma resposta rebuscada, respondi em menos e cinco minutos enquanto almoçava, mas já é a minha mais popular. Em duas horas, ultrapassou/empatou todas as minhas outras, mesmo as que demoraram uma semana para alcançar 5 pontos.